# Sharing application configurations across a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration-files, config

I have a solution which has multiple output projects (a website, and admin tool, and a SOAP API layer).

They each share common projects in the solution (the service layer, data layer etc). In one of these common projects, I am looking to store a config layer.

Right now, we have three seperate appsettings config files for each output project -

- `development.AppSettings.config`
- `testing.AppSettings.config`
- `production.AppSettings.config`

So altogether, there are nine config files. Only one is used in each project, as they are referenced by utilising the [configSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228167.aspx) attribute in the web.config appsettings node.

Anyhoo, it's getting to be a pain any time we want to add/remove values from our config files, because it means that we have to change all **nine** files to do this. And here's what I'd like to do:

In the common project, we have three config files as above. These would be set to copy to the output directory, so that each project has a copy of them. These would be the 'base' config.

Then in each project, I would like to have three files again, but they wouldn't necessarily have to contain the same values as the base configs. *If they did however, then the base config value would be overridden by the value in the output project config. A form of configuration inheritance, I suppose.*

On application start, I'd like to be able to get these two config files - the base config, and the project config file. And then set the app settings accordingly.

What I'm wondering though, is what's a nice way of determining which file to use? Also, I'm wondering if this is a good way of sharing application values across a large solution, and if there's another, perhaps more efficient way of doing it?

If I'm in development mode, then I don't want production.appsettings.config, and vice versa if I'm in production mode.

Is there a simple way to get the mode (development/testing/production) that I'm in before I go off and get the configurations?

Comment: To double check, each appsettings.config file has unique key/value for each project, in addition, there are overlapping key/value pairs used by all projects?

Comment: There are overlapping key/value pairs. Such as, ApplicationMode. This is set to Dev,Testing or Production depending on which *.appsettings.config it is in. Each project can also have their own unique config values that are not used by the other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some careful thought, and a trip to the toilet at 03:30, I came across a solution which works.

Let's say that we have some appSettings in our base config file:

```
<add key="MyKey1" value="MyValue1" />
<add key="MyKey2" value="MyValue2" />
<!-- And so on... -->
<add key="MyKey5" value="MyValue5" />
```

And in my output project, I have three appSettings:

```
<!-- This is used to identify which config to use. -->
<add key="Config" value="Development" />

<!-- Different value to the one in the base -->
<add key="MyKey2" value="NewValue2" />

<!-- This key does not exist in the base config -->
<add key="MyKey6" value="MyValue6" />
```

In my Application_Start, I have a call to `GetConfigs()`:

ConfigHelper.GetConfig(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin/BaseConfig"));

And the actual GetConfigs function:

```
public static void GetConfigs()
{
  if (configMode == null)
  {
    configMode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Config").ToLowerInvariant();
  }

  //Now load the app settings file and retrieve all the config values.
  var config = XElement.Load(@"{0}\AppSettings.{1}.config".FormatWith(directory, configMode))
    .Elements("add")
    .Select(x => new { Key = x.Attribute("key").Value, Value = x.Attribute("value").Value })
    //If the current application instance does not contain this key in the config, then add it.
    //This way, we create a form of configuration inheritance.
    .Where(x => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(x.Key) == null);

  foreach (var configSetting in config)
  {
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set(configSetting.Key, configSetting.Value);
  }
}
```

Now, my output project effectively has the following configuration settings:

```
<add key="Config" value="Development" />
<add key="MyKey1" value="MyValue1" />
<add key="MyKey2" value="NewValue2" />
<!-- And so on... -->
<add key="MyKey5" value="MyValue5" />
<add key="MyKey6" value="MyValue6" />
```

Simples!

Comment: I hate to dredge up and reanimate a buried question, but... How did work out for you. I am working through a similar issue with many projects in a single solution and was looking for some sort of inheritance within web/app configs. Also do you think this would work for other sections of the config (custom sections or connections)?

Comment: @William The proposed solution worked brilliantly and allows for configuration inheritance from a core set of values so that they can be overridden and/or supplemented. Regarding other sections, I haven't really approached it, but I don't see why it couldn't be adapted for others configs.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one set of files (3 configs) and link/share them in whatever projects you need.

http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18855

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to do that. The output projects need to be allowed to have their own values as well, so there needs to some form of value inheritance going on. If I change a value in project x, I don't want that value to be used in project y. However, if I change a value in the base config, then I expect projects x,y and z to have them (unless they overwrite it with their own!).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) static method. This will allow you to work with as many config files as you want.

You may also try creating a custom class to store all of your settings. You could then serialize your object to save it as a file. You could extend your base custom config class to fit all your other projects.

Comment: This may be a nice way to do the config file loading, but does it apply to configsources? It looks like it's specifically for web.configs and not files that are sections.